# R.Java error - Android Developer Studio -Eclipse-

Tags: android, resources, r.java-file

I have a nasty problem with R.Java in Eclipse, when trying to add new images to a newly created folder on my Res (drawable). what could be the problem ? Nothing happens after cleaning the project...

Comment: could you post you error log?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error it contains a lot of possible problems

Comment: post the logcat error or the error you are facing ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using **non-compliant names** for your resources (like file with *uppercase* letters).

Please read the [Android naming conventions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the image you copy have all letters in the filename as smallcase . This could be one issue. File name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]

Answer (score 0):

I had faced many times same problem.
try the below steps. it could help you.
In Eclipse
 1. Enable Problems view by clicking,
Windows->ShowView->Problems
check the problem and solve.
 2. Remove R.java from gen folder of your eclipse try to build it again.
 3. Check for Import **R** in your project. sometime eclipse imports android.R instead of **yourclassname**.R
 4. Check for your XML file where sometimes id will not generate if you add it manually in xml file.
 5. Reopen the project.

Hope it helps.